# Placing ListView DataItem Property into UserControl Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview, user-controls

Sort of new to .NET and trying to understand how best to accomplish this task: I have a listview with a datasource containing a list of string values.  The last property is some text that I'd like to place in the Text template; normally when not used inside a listview I can place markup and text inside the template successfully, so I'd like to keep this structure.  But what would be a way of placing that string inside there?  I've tried Databinder.Eval but as expected it says that the template doesn't contain the property I'm referring to from Container.DataItem (which becomes the template).

```
<asp:ListView runat="server"
    ID="ListView1"
    OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">

    <LayoutTemplate>

        <div class="navigation">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </div>

    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

        <my:Control id="VideoLink1" runat="server">
            <Text>
                --- PLACE CONTENT HERE --
            </Text>
        </my:Control>

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?  Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These templates only exist in the context of the ListView...

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do is, once data is bound to the dataitem, is there a way to utilize <%# Eval %> within the Text template.  Or maybe is this something I may have to do in a codefile (but again, not sure how that would be accomplished).

Comment: Put it in session state and use a label?

Answer (score 1):

Use ItemDatabound event of the ListView. In that find your control and then assign the desired properties.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            YourControl  VideoLink1= e.Item.FindControl("VideoLink1") as YourControl ;
            if(VideoLink1!= null)
            {
                YourClass obj = ((YourClass)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem)(e.Item)).DataItem));
               VideoLink1.TextProperty = obj .TextProperty ;
           }    
       }
}
```